# "Odin’s tears will drown the world of men on the day" — what does this sentence mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence

Here is the passage:

> The skies will burst open and Odin’s tears will drown the world of men on the day when JaVale McGee’s body syncs up naturally with his team on the basketball court.
>
> Until that day, however, we’re going to sit back and enjoy living on a planet where professional basketball players like McGee are free to flail.

By the way, I know nothing about Odin.

Comment: Did you [look him up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin)?

Comment: Off topic: literature (such as it is) analysis.

Comment: @MετάEd Agree as Off Topic. However, there are any number of such questions going around -- with plenty of up votes for both Qs as well answers such as Andrew Leach's here. I vote to close.

Answer (score 4):

The quote is from [Sports events that would prove the world is ending](http://bleacherreport.com/articles/1452970-sports-events-that-would-prove-the-world-is-ending/page/3).

The event of Odin's tears drowning the world is so unlikely to happen as to be impossible. The author is of the opinion that JaVale McGee is so selfish that he will never actually improve, even if he was given all the time in the world.

Or: the world will only end once JaVale McGee becomes a good team player, which is a *very* long time away.

Either way, the author has resorted to a colourful image of implausibility to illustrate his opinion of the player.

Comment: I think the implication is that McGee is a selfish player who does not coordinate with his teammates, not that he is unskilled.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Thanks. I'm not a basketball player and the video isn't exactly clear.

Comment: You are more confident of sportswriters’ literacy than I. I suspect that this writer has mixed up his Norse gods either through misremembering or (more likely) being misinformed about or (most likely) misremembering second-hand information about this passage in Snorri’s Prose Edda: “How should one periphrase Baldr? By calling him Son of Odin and Frigg, Husband of Nanna, Father of Forseti, [...] **God of Tears**.” Snorri refers to the tale that all the world wept at Baldr’s death—except the giantess Thökk, who refused, thus preventing Baldr’s escape from Hel.